# box sizing using a global css file

Tags: css, import

Do I still have to add

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

in every css file, if I am using a global css file, in which I @import all my css files.

And while we are at it: Is it possible to add a favicon to my global css file with @import or something like that?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for, you are providing code for `box-sizing` and asking for a favicon

Comment: No, just add the styles in one of your file that will be loaded. Or better, in your global css file. As for the favicon, you can't add it through CSS.

Comment: @import will delay the loading of your CSS , not sure it is the best to do. For your reset, set it only once within the css file that is always loaded through your pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not have to. Its available to all css below it in the file that it is placed and all the files imported below the file that it is placed. Adding a favicon is done in the header section of the html files i.e `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="path/to/favicon.png">`